# Why can't I capture a MetaInspector::TimeoutError inside an Async block in Ruby 3 with Async 2.3.0 and MetaInspector 5.13.0?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, web-scraping, metainspector

I am using Ruby 3.0.0, MetaInspector 5.13.0, and socketry's Async 2.3.0 to scrape the meta from a list of urls. I set the connection and read timeouts as per the documentation for MetaInspector and test with httpbin's delay endpoint. MetaInspector's documentation notes I should be able to capture a MetaInspector::Timeout error but instead the Async block errors out uncaptured, even if I capture all errors. Here is my test script called timeout_error.rb:

```
require 'async'
require 'metainspector'

urls = ["https://httpbin.org/delay/15", "https://www.google.com"]

Async do 

  urls.each do |url|

    Async do

      begin
        page = MetaInspector.new(url, connection_timeout: 10, read_timeout: 5, allow_non_html_content: true)
      rescue MetaInspector::TimeoutError
        puts "rescued MetaInspector's TimeoutError"
      rescue => e
        puts "rescued everything else, type: #{e.class}, message: #{e.message}"
      end

      puts "made it to the end of the nested Async block with #{url}"
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my output from the shell:

```
meta_collector git:(master) ✗ ruby -v
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin21]
meta_collector git:(master) ✗ ruby bin/timeout_error.rb
made it to the end of the nested Async block with https://www.google.com
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/async-2.3.0/lib/async/scheduler.rb:213:in `select': execution expired (Timeout::Error)
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/async-2.3.0/lib/async/scheduler.rb:213:in `run_once'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/async-2.3.0/lib/async/scheduler.rb:232:in `run'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/async-2.3.0/lib/kernel/async.rb:32:in `Async'
    from bin/timeout_error.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I expect to see once the "rescued everything else..." alongside two "made it to the end of the nested.." output, but I never do. Anyone have any insights here?

Comment: So it appears your issue is not that you can't rescue the error but that that error is occurring outside of your rescue. The async task is actually what is timing out

Comment: Do I need to look into how to increase the timeout window for my async tasks then?